# USB 3.0 Not Working

Tags: usb, windows-8-preview

I bought an Asus A43E laptop which comes with one USB 3.0 port. 
In Windows 7 it was working just fine, but after Windows 8 has been installed the USB doesnt work anymore.
 When I insert any flash drive windows has no reaction.

I have been trying to find a driver but I couldnt find one that fits.

I know this port works cause I am able to boot windows throw a flash drive.
 It might be some driver missing. You guys have any idea how can I solve this?

Comment: What exactly **is** working on this laptop of yours? It seems like everyday, 3 other pieces break.

Comment: sorry i did not catch you

Comment: [internet explorer is broken](http://superuser.com/questions/438931/internet-explorer-not-networking), [bluetooth broken](http://superuser.com/questions/438917/bluetooth-devices-not-detecting), [USB broken](http://superuser.com/questions/438927/usb-3-0-not-working), ...

Comment: I think no damage at all

Comment: Don't install beta test software on your main computing system. Report all bugs back to Microsoft. It's how they learn what's not working. Probably, a driver from ASUS isn't compatible with Win8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB 3.0 resides on a separate controller, and it needs a driver.  You should check with the vendor of the laptop to see if there's a Windows 8 compatible driver out for this yet.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact problem as OP. I upgraded my Windows 7 to Windows 8 about 2 weeks ago, and suddenly ALL 8 of my USBs did not work.

I had MS Answerdesk perform diagnostics TWICE to try and fix it, the last time they said their level 2 agents had to work on the computer (but never called).

After searching online for the last 2 WEEKS, and finding no definitive answers as to actually fix this problem, I had to do one thing first: download [AI Charger](http://event.asus.com/mb/2010/ai_charger/).

I was going to install and uninstall the program to see if it did anything, since AI Charger didn't show up on the populated programs list.

There were 3 options after I unzipped and loaded setup. Repair, Install and The bottom option was "REMOVE".  I chose remove, as I didn't even know the program was on my computer (didn't show up on the populated programs list) and it forced a restart.

After restart: all of my USBs were working.

Answer (score 0):

All USB 3.0 drivers required for your flash drive to work should be inbox in Windows 8. Can you try two things:

1. Look for a firmware update for the USB 3.0 controller on the OEM (Asus) website.
2. Move to Windows 8 Release Preview if you are currently running Developer Preview or Consumer Preview.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem too. But, thanks to asus team for submitting their updates to windows update. I performed complete

## windows update.

Now, I have ***USB 3.0*** & ***Bluetooth 3.0*** working like a charm.